# Regex replace text outside html tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on an autocomplete component that highlights all ocurrences of searched text. What I do is explode the input text by words, and wrap every ocurrence of those words into a

My code looks like this

```
inputText = 'marriott st';
text = "Marriott east side";
textSearch = inputText.split(' ');
for (var i in textSearch) {
  var regexSearch = new RegExp('(?!<\/?strong>)' + textSearch[i]), "i");
  var textReplaced = regexSearch.exec(text);
  text = text.replace(regexSearch, '< strong>' + textReplaced + '< /strong>');
}
```

For example, given the result: "marriott east side"

And the input text: "marriott st"

I should get

```
  <strong>marriot< /strong > ea < strong >st < /strong > side
```

And i'm getting

```
  <<strong>st</strong>rong>marriot</<strong>st </strong>rong>ea<<strong>st</strong> rong>s</strong> side
```

Any ideas how can I improve my regex, in order to avoid ocurrences inside the html tags? Thanks

```
   /(?!<\/?strong>)st/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would process the string in one pass. You can create one regular expression out of the search string:

```
var search_pattern = '(' + inputText.replace(/\s+/g, '|') + ')';
// `search_pattern` is now `(marriot|st)`
text = text.replace(RegExp(search_pattern, 'gi'), '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uL3GK/)

You could even split the search string first, sort the words by length and combine them, to give a higher precedence to longer matches.

You definitely should escape special regex characters inside the string: [How to escape regular expression special characters using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript).

Comment: That's absolutely great! So much simpler... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before each search, I suggest getting (or saving) the original search string to work on each time.  For example, in your current case that means you could replace all '<strong>' and '</strong>' tags with ''.  This will help keep your regEx simple, especially if you decide to add other html tags and formatting in the future.