# Why does this javascript regex return false?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp which should return true if a given string foo ends with the given string bar. E.g:

```
function solution(str, ending)
{
  var pattern = "/" + ending + "$/";
  var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
  console.log( str + ", " + ending + " , " + regex.source);
  return regex.test(str);
}
```

However, if I test this using the following input:

```
console.log( solution("samurai", "ai") );
```

I get the following console output:

```
samurai, ai , /ai$/
false
```

The pattern seems correct to me, so why is it returning false for 'samurai' ending with 'ai' ?

Comment: I think you should read more about regexes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions , as well as understanding the use of an "escape" function, in case the `pattern` may include regex characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invoke the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor, you don't need to put `/` characters around your pattern. That's only for when you're using a regular expression literal.

Try this:

```
function solution(str, ending)
{
  var pattern = ending + "$";
  var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
  console.log( str + ", " + ending + " , " + regex.source);
  return regex.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`new RegExp("/foo/")` is `/\/foo\//`. The slashes are only needed when you're constructing a regex literal.

Take out the slashes from your string and it'll work.

You can also do this without regex:

```
str.lastIndexOf(ending) === str.length - ending.length;
```