# global replace doesn't work , but simple replace works fine

Tags: javascript

i have a simple smily parser code :

```
for (var key in smiles) {
  text = text.replace(key  , smiles[key]);
}
return text;
```

so the problem is , this will only replace the first one so i've switched to global replace

```
for (var key in smiles) {
  var r =  '/'+key+'/g';
  console.log(r);
  text = text.replace(r  , smiles[key]);
}
```

in console  i have :

```
/:)/g
/;)/g
/:(/g
```

which seems to be ok , but it wont replace any of these codes `:)  ;)  :(`
whats wrong ?

Comment: Where `key = ':\\)'` you want `r = new RegExp(key,'g');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression literal (`/foo/g`) is not the same as a string that looks like a regular expression literal (`"/foo/g"`).

You can create regular expressions dynamically using the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var r = new RegExp(key, 'g');
```

And that’s the point at which you’ll get parenthesis-related errors. [You can escape your values to put in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript) – put together in the nicest way, it might look something like this:

```
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[[{}()*+?.\\^$|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function replaceAll(str, map) {
    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(map).map(escapeRegex).join("|"), "g");

    return str.replace(re, function(m) {
        return map[m];
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah , i get : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:)/: Unmatched ')'

Comment: A bit nasty having *map* as a local variable and also calling the *map* method.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep looping through the text and replacing the smiley until there are no more occurrences:-

```
for (var key in smiles) {
    while (text.indexOf(key) > -1) {
        text = text.replace(key, smiles[key]);
    }
}
return text;
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation.

Comment: thanx , it's kinda overkill ... at least my browser thinks that ... both firefox and chrome

Comment: just trying to offer an alternative to people who's brains don't compute regular expressions (like mine)...