# jQuery: Real-time search

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build real-time search project but i am not sure what wrong with my code. if i search "AAA - AAA" a results is show but when i search "TOF0042 - text update + resize" a results not show up.

Could you help me?

- HTML Code

> ```
> <input type="text" id="search-project" name="search-project">
> <ul class="list-porject">
>     <li>AAA - AAA</li>
>     <li>BBB - BBB</li>
>     <li>0546 - Testing</li>
>     <li>TOF0042 - text update + resize</li>
> </ul>
> ```

- jQuery Code

> (function($){
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $("#search-project").keyup(function(){        
>        var filter = $(this).val();                
>        $(".list-porject li").each(function(){
>            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
>          $(this).addClass('hidden');
>          } else {
>                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
>     } 
>        });
> ```
>
> });
>       })})(jQuery);

- CSS

> .hidden {    display:none; }

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pPn9/)

Comment: As best I understand it, your fiddle works for either search.

Comment: Did you search for "TOF0042 - text update + resize"? 
Can you copy and paste this word into textbox search? you will know what problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "TOF0042 - text update + resize" you have the character "+", which is a quantifier in Regular expressions.

To search "TOF0042 - text update + resize" you will need to check for special character within your string. In this case `+` should be `\+`.

[How to escape special characters using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310752/1288883)

[More info about Javascript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8R9VS/)

Comment: Check the link I've included