# Preg_match php explaination

Tags: php, regex

I have a question regarding one character in the `preg_match` syntax below.
I just want to completely understand.
`\w` looking for alpha-numberic characters and the underscore.

My question is what does the `\` mean after `\w` and before the `@` sign?

Does this mean that it will allow:

1. any alphanumeric
2. any backslash
3. any dash

or is this backslash meant to single out the character that follows?

When I test it in w3schools.com example I can have backslashes in the email address which validates but they are removed when they are echoed out.

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
      {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
      }
```

Comment: I don't think you really need a backslash there. It is usually used to escape a character that follows after it.

Comment: \ is there to escape strings. http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php. Also you can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript

Comment: thanks the below from the link explained exactly what I needed to know                                                                                                                               Escape sequences ¶

The backslash character has several uses. Firstly, if it is followed by a non-alphanumeric character, it takes away any special meaning that character may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is used to escape characters that have a special meaning in a regex to obtain a literal character. There are twelve characters that must be escaped: `[ { ( ) . ? * + | \ ^ $`

If I want to write a literal `$` in a pattern, I must write `\$`

Note: you don't need to escape `{` if the situation is no ambiguous (with the quantifier `{m,n}` or `{m}`)

Note 2: The delimiter of the pattern must be escaped too, inside and outside a character class.

Inside a character class these twelve characters don't need no more to be escaped since they loose their special meaning and are seen as literals. However, there is three characters that have a special meaning if they are in a special position in the character class. These characters are: `^ - ]`

`^` at the first position is used to negate a character class (`[^M]` => *all that is not a M* ). If you want to use it as a literal character at "the first position", you must write: `[\^]`

`-` between two characters defines a character range (`[a-z]`). This means that you don't need to escape it at the begining (or immediatly after ^) or at the end of the class. You only need to escape it between two characters. `-` is seen as a literal (and doesn't define a range) in all these examples:

```
[-abcd]
[^-abcd]
[abcd-]
[ab\-cd]
[\s-abcd]   # because \s is not a character
```

`]` since it is used to close the character class must be escaped except at the first position or immediatly after the `^`. `[]]` and `[^]]` are correct.

If I write the pattern without uneeded backslashes, I obtain:

```
/([\w-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w-]+)/
```

To answer your question ("What does it mean?"): Nothing, uneeded escapes are ignored by the regex engine.