# How to make JavaScript ignore escape characters in object's field

Tags: javascript, json, mathjax

The javascript file that would be imported:

```
let objek = {
    "subjek": "10mat",
    "10mat1": {
        "id": "10mat1",
        "noPertanyaan": 1,
        "pertanyaan": "",
        "jawaban": {
            "a": "$ b - a < x - y < a - b  $",
            "b": "$ a - b < x - y < b - a  $",
            "c": "$ \frac {1}{2}\\ (b-a) < x - y < \frac {1}{2}\\ (a-b) $",
            "d": "$ \frac {1}{2}\\ (a-b) < x - y < \frac {1}{2}\\ (b-a) $"
        },
        "kunci": "c"
    },
    "10mat2": {
        "id": "10mat2",
        "noPertanyaan": 2,
        "pertanyaan": "",
        "jawaban": {
            "a": "$ 2 [\leq x \leq 3 $",
            "b": "$ -1 \leq x \leq 2 $",
            "c": "$ x \leq{2}\ \text{atau}\ x \geq{3}\ $",
            "d": "$ x \leq{-1}\ \text{atau}\ x \geq{2}\ $"
        },
        "kunci": "e"
    }
}

module.exports = objek
```

When I import this file, and I JSON.stringify and JSON.parse it, `$ -1 \leq x \leq 2 $` becomes `$ -1 leq x leq 2 $`, how can I fix this / make the JSON parser ignore the escape characters intended for a TeX syntax?

I tried to turn `\` into `\\` and also tried using `.raw` but both don't work. I used a JS file instead of JSON because JSON wouldn't accept invalid escape characters but JS does, at least its what it seems. Like I said above, it simply ruins the TeX syntax when it's imported, even before it gets stringified and parsed.

I'm trying to write mathematical equations with MathJax so that it wouldn't be hard to display TeX on HTML, but as it turns out, I'm bombarded by problems on escape characters instead.

Comment: Replace \ with \\, then just `JSON.parse(objek)` will work.

Comment: Doesn't work. Can you elaborate on how you managed to get it working?

Comment: OK, take a look at this https://codepen.io/magicjack/pen/dyYzqqW?editors=0111

Comment: Check the console log

Comment: I checked the codepen and it did work. Though I then tried to replicate it in my code (nodejs) and it doesn't work. Any idea on how one could fix this in NodeJS? Thanks tho

Comment: Do you have a demo environment?  like repl.it or ...

Comment: Do you have read this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465978/how-to-escape-characters-in-nodejs

Comment: Hi again, yeah I've read the stackoverflow entry you've commented but it didn't help. I'm not sure where I can put a sandbox of NodeJS so I put it in a gist instead (https://gist.github.com/drepram/54592e976f51aa6d9cfd3f65ac8bce10). Right now I'm thinking about letting it be a \\ and just parsing at FE, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: I built one on "repl.it" https://repl.it/@MagicJack/Escape-Character, and that is still right for what I had recommended.