# Why does not this string pass test function?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I do:

```
var input_string = "(1) (1) test.txt";
var reg = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+' + input_string,'i');
var tested_string = "(1) (1) (1) test.txt";
alert(reg.test(tested_string)); // returns false
```

I expect it to return true, but it does not. I wonder, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape all parenthesis, and you are not. Adding the `\\` to the `(` on the input string would make it work:

```
var input_string = "\\(1\\) \\(1\\) test.txt"; // fixed
var reg = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+' + input_string,'i');
var tested_string = "(1) (1) (1) test.txt";
alert(reg.test(tested_string)); // returns true now
```

would work.

If you need to use **arbitrary strings** in the regex, **you need to escape** them. I suggest you use a function like the one below before adding it to the `RegExp` object:

```
function escapeRegExp(stringToGoIntoTheRegex) {
    return stringToGoIntoTheRegex.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

In your case it could be like:

```
var input_string = "(1) (1) test.txt";
var reg = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+' + escapeRegExp(input_string),'i'); // using it here
var tested_string = "(1) (1) (1) test.txt";
alert(reg.test(tested_string)); // returns true as expected
```

See [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oq6dmtba/).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was first, and I will accept it, as soon as stackoverflow allows me to do it -)

Comment: Np. Make sure you check the `escapeRegExp()` function. It could prove itself useful in the future!

Comment: There is no need to escape `/` at all. It has no special meaning in regex if you construct it via RegExp constructor.

Comment: @nhahtdh There are several implementations of that function around the internet, some include `/`, some don't. I do agree escaping it seems to be unecessary, but some [do report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript#comment47308991_9310752) having problems when not escaping. So, yeah, I guess depending on the concrete situation we can make it "optional".

Comment: @acdcjunior Do note that the author of the answer doesn't update the post after comment, and if you read his blog, he write stuffs about ES6 regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, we have no evidence that the `/` requires escaping other than complaints about tools and whatnot. So, ultimately, if one doesn't want to escape the `/`, one doesn't have to, though escaping it doesn't hurt either - as far as evidences go as well.

Answer (score 5):

Because you do not escape the `(` and `)` which makes them capture groups. Also the period also needs to be escaped so it is not a match anything character.

```js
    var input_string = "\\(1\\) \\(1\\) test\\.txt";
    var reg = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+' + input_string,'i');
    var tested_string = "(1) (1) (1) test.txt";
    alert(reg.test(tested_string)); // returns false
```