# regexp with modifiers in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

How to escape all special charactors (modifiers) in the pattern?

In this snippet of code the var `input` contains a modifier `*`.. How to escape all special characters in the input (pattern) variable?

```
var input = '*dog',
    regexp = new RegExp(input, 'ig'),
    str = 'a *dog and a cat';

if(str.search(regexp) >= 0){
    console.log('found!');
}
else{
    console.log('not found!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8511wfbk/1/

Comment: Did you try to escape the special chars? var input = '\\\*dog'

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript