# JavaScript code to remove the special characters []{}<>

Tags: javascript, regex

Could any one suggest code to remove mentioned special characters: `[]{}<>`

Code inside the JavaScript tags:

```
var name="formattting[]{}<>";

rename = name.replace(/[<{>}([)]/g,"");
```

Output:

```
formattting]
```

Here out of six special symbols, five symbols are removed and now my concern is to remove the special character `]`.

Comment: You need to escape all special Characters with \
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript

Comment: @PhilippBlum: In character classes, all you need to escape are `]`,``\`` and `-`.

Comment: Was writing `9` instead of `]` intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rename = name.replace(/[[\]{}<>]/g, "");
```

Comment: old code:
var name="formattting[]{}<>hdsdshd";
var removed=name.replace(/[<{>}([)]/g,"");

new code thats works
rename = name.replace(/[[\]{}<>]/g, "");

this new code works :) thanks for time timolawl

Comment: You're welcome! Accept this answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters in regex:

```
var name="formattting[]{}<>";
rename = name.replace(/[\$<{>}9\(\[\)\]]/g,"");
alert(rename)
```

Comment: Don't overescape. And why didn't you escape the `$` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape the `\]`

```
var name="formattting[]{}<>";
var rename = name.replace(/[<{>}([)\]]/g,"");

alert(rename);
```