# Fuzzy Searching with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, search, mongoose

I have managed to set up a search feature in my mongodb app. See the code below. This works very well however it only returns exact results. How would I change my code to make it accept more "fuzzy" search results? Thanks!

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    if (req.query.search) {
       Jobs.find({"name": req.query.search}, function(err, foundjobs){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
          res.render("jobs/index",{jobs:foundjobs});
       }
    }); 
    }

  Jobs.find({}, function(err, allJobs){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
          res.render("jobs/index",{jobs:allJobs});
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use a mongoose FullText library for most accurate searches https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fulltext

Comment: in case anybody's interested, i've written an article on how to do fuzzy searching in mongodb with c# [here](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/mongodb-fuzzy-text-search-with-c-the-easy-way-3l8j)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe that to do "fuzzy" search you will need to use regex. This should accomplish what you're looking for (escapeRegex function source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)):

```
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.search) {
       const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
       Jobs.find({ "name": regex }, function(err, foundjobs) {
           if(err) {
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.render("jobs/index", { jobs: foundjobs });
           }
       }); 
    }
}
```

That being said, your application can experience performance issues when querying mongo by regex. Using a library like [search-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/search-index) for search could help optimize your application's performance, with the added benefit of searching word stems (like returning "found" from "find").

---

UPDATE: My original answer included a simple regular exression that would leave your application vulnerable to a [regex DDoS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS). I've updated with a "safe" escaped regex.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is an old thread, but I made a plugin which is based on [this article](https://medium.com/xeneta/fuzzy-search-with-mongodb-and-python-57103928ee5d).

[mongoose-fuzzy-searching](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fuzzy-searching)

(It uses `$text` query operator instead of `$regex`, for faster results)

The below example just searches for events based on title and city

```
const mongoose_fuzzy_searching = require('mongoose-fuzzy-searching');

const schema = {
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
    }
};

const EventsSchema = mongoose.Schema(schema);
EventsSchema.plugin(mongoose_fuzzy_searching, {fields: ['title', 'city']});

const Events = mongoose.model('Events', EventsSchema);

Events.fuzzySearch('Nodejs meetup').then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: @Vassilis Pallas  Does this use the partial index or not. I need to remove the documents from the index when the condition does not met. For eg I only want to add in the index when user_status is ACTIVE only

Comment: @VassilisPallas If I delete the ngram from the particular document. Will it get removed from the index as well ?

Comment: To delete the ngrams from documents you can use
[this logic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fuzzy-searching#delete-old-ngrams-from-all-documents). 
Now regarding the indexes, if you removed the plugin from the Collection, you will need also to delete them from the database as well

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Mongo DB Atlas feature where you can search your text based on different [Analyzers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/) that MongoDB provides.
And you can then do a search like this:
Without the fuzzy object, it would do a full-text-match search.

```
$search:{
 {
  index: 'analyzer_name_created_from_atlas_search',
  text: {
    query: 'Russ has denied involvement in the case',
    path: 'sentence',
    fuzzy:{
      maxEdits: 2
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated answer that comes on the heels of a new product in MongoDB that was not released at the time of the original post. MongoDB now has a feature where you can deploy Apache Lucene indexes to get robust fuzzy search functionality, and other features like synonyms, highlighting and autocomplete.

Below is the syntax as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556615/mongodb-atlas-search-v-s-match/66556730#66556730) in another answer I had.

```
{
  $search: {
    "index": <index name>, // optional, defaults to "default"
    "text": {
      "query": "queryText",
      "path": "<fields-to-search>",
      "fuzzy": {
         "maxEdits": 2
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using atlas go to the index tab create an index for your database then you can use aggregate for a more powerful fuzzy search.

```
Jobs.aggregate([
    {
        $search: {
            "index": "default",
            "text": {
                "path": "name",
                "query": req.query.search,
            }
        }
    },
], (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
}).limit(20)
```