# NodeJS-PassportJS Giving The Certain Password

Tags: node.js, express, passwords

I am making a admin which will request just for a certain passport.
But when I type it I cannot log in ? How can I solve it ?

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        password:{
            type: String,
            required: true
          }
    });
    const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In my command line, I created a users collectin and inserted a password:'sifre'

This is my password.js :

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(passport){
  // Local Strategy
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(password){

    let query = {password:password};
    User.findOne(query, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
      }


  /*Also I have tried:
    // Match Username
    let query = {username:username};
    User.findOne(query, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
      } */


    /* to understand if it is about user name. Even I added username to models, db.collections 
and other code pages but I couldnt solve. Because again
 I couldnt reflect the models to db, I think.*/

      // Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });

  });
}
```

Also this is my user.js:

```
    const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

let User = require('../models/user');

// Register Form
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    const password = req.body.password;
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    res.render('login');
  });

  router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect:'/',
      failureRedirect:'/users/login',
      failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
  });

  // logout
  router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged out');
    res.redirect('/login');
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

And also this is my command line

```
db.createCollection('users');
...
db.users.insert{(password:'123'});
...
```

So how can I implement the inserted password to these code blocks. I cannot understand why it is not working. For now I dont get any errors but when I type that inserted password, I cannot move to user page.

Edit:

```
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        console.log("asd");
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

This part is not working.(which is in passport.js)

Also I cannot entegrate the module(user.js) o my mongodb.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I editted, can you please look at it again ?

Comment: After typing and submitting your password from the client, can you confirm that the password local strategy is executed? If it was executed, what is the output of the `User.findOne` query?

Comment: I thing the User.Find works well but bcyrtp.password(....) part is not working. When I tried the code with console.log(Username is found) - (Password is found). It shows Username is found in that npm console but it doesnt show password is found.