# Admin Password(Log in with a one password to webiste)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, admin

I have procjet which will allow only admin to post and log in without username or registiration. So that I just used Password. But where I stack is, the issue that me and some of my friends which are involved to therese codings couldnt solve.
This is a page that I referenced the code and the issue is same:[NodeJS-PassportJS Giving The Certain Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228711/nodejs-passportjs-giving-the-certain-password?noredirect=1#comment106532763_60228711)

I have been using passport.js, nodejs and express.js with pug template.

This is my user.js model:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
});
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

This is my passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(passport){
  // Local Strategy
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(password){

    let query = {password:password};
    User.findOne(query, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
      }

      // Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });

  });
}
```

This is my users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

let User = require('../models/user');

// Register Form
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    const password = req.body.password;
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    res.render('login');
  });

  router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect:'/',
      failureRedirect:'/users/login',
      failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
  });

  // logout
  router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged out');
    res.redirect('/login');
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

Also in db I have cerated a collection called user", because when I tried to do it with my code I find out the user. Maybe the problem can be in user.js(Models) or passport.js
this is my comamnd line mongodb:

```
db.createCollection('users');
...
db.users.insert{(password:'123'});
...
```

I need yout help, please it is my school homework and I have promised for that, I want to apply my promise. Please help to me. How can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

by default passport.js LocalStrategy gets function like this:

```
    function(username, password, done){//...}
```

Or, if you set { passReqToCallback: true }:

```
    function(req, username, password, done){//...}
```

So, if you pass only one argument it will be username.

I think that you can solve it so:

```
    function(username, password, done){
         // Here's your code where you can not use 'username' and everything will be fine
    }
```

Comment: I couldnt solve it can you please look at this NodeJS-PassportJS Giving The Certain Password page I am following that topic for my project. So the issue is same. I am using the same codes.