# How to unable user to choose tags for one of the register form field?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, pug, searchbar

I'm building a nodejs express app with mongoDB. 
I want to make user be able to choose certain predefined tags when submitting a register form.

Register for studios, an attribute is "equipment”，want user to choose from tags "drums","guitar","amp","mic", etc.

And I want to use the tags for search bar function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it active now or did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So, at the database, you can create a model with 'tags' of `String` data type. Make an `app.post('someURL/:tag')`. Get the value of tag using `req.params` , check if the `tags` in your `model` is empty, if it's not , set its value otherwise send back an error.
Anytime you click on the frontend, make a req to the backend using the same API point

Comment: sorry but i want something like when we post question on stackoverflow we can choose to add multiple tags "html" "javascript".

Comment: well, that is CSS and JS . It is not related to backend , change the tags of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You want to open a tag system. If you do it for user when you search tags you will find users. But in your project there are articles which user can post, it is better to add tags to articles.

I will just show a example.

**In your Model.js script just add:**

```
tags:{
  type:String,
  required:True,//If you want to make tags as a obligation.
},
```

**You should look at here:**
[Mongodb Nodejs Regex Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836933/mongodb-nodejs-regex-search)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_lKMTXVk64

[Fuzzy Searching with Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421664/fuzzy-searching-with-mongodb)

**Add a search.pug:(Or add form in your layout, it depends on your preferences)**

```
 form.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0(action="/sonuc" method="GET")
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here..." class="form-control">
```

After that in your app.js(or whatever you name it):

**You can also look here:** 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#examples

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res){
  if (req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    Article.find({"tags": regex}, function(err, articles) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
           res.render("index", { 
             articles: articles 
            });
        }
    });
  }
});
```

**And in article.pug:**

```
.
.
input.form-control(name='', type='text')
.
.
```

In app.js you will just add these codes to add articles(post)

```
let article = new Article({
...
...
...
tags:req.body.tags,
});
```

You can just change the codes and follow the steps. But I recomend you to write these scripts to your notebook. And then write the meanings of them.

In this project, you will use **regex**.

Please look at the links that I have send to you and then please write scripts in your notebook and write the meaning of codes.(To learn the structure and steps.)