# mongodb array query for search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, searchbar

I am trying to return documents where at least one element from the selected field array matches the query array.

I have tried the following queries:

```
const match_equipment = await studios.find({equipment: {$eleMatch:{$in: ["mic","amp"]}}});
```

```
const match_equipment = await studios.find({equipment: {$all: ["mic","amp"]}});
```

The 1st query gives me "db query failed error" 2nd one gives me "no result found".

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5ec5d38be97c8869bee29e78"},
    "equipment": ["guitar", " mic", " amp"],
    "studio_name": "Best recordings",
    "email": "changed@gmail.com",
    "address": "34 harming st. Brunswick",
    "postcode": "3056",
    "price": "50",
    "__v": {"$numberInt": "0"},
    "unavalibility": [
        {
            "times": [{"$numberInt": "13"}],
            "_id": {"$oid": "5ec610e47cf2fb4e84ba0c54"}, "date": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1591920000000"}}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The second one should work, you can see a working example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/l8tqUZY5xAU

Comment: Please do not use images for code or text but add relevant code fragments or listings to you question.

Comment: sorry first time code; didn't know how it should work. i will copy paste my code

Comment: @PuneetSingh thank you! i found out the problem, it's my document actually has a space before "mic" as " mic". i will try add regexp !

Comment: Sorry follow up question, how should i add regular expression for fuzzy search? i am not very familiar with it but tried this did't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421664/fuzzy-searching-with-mongodb

eg. if i want document with "DRUM" or "   drum"  can all be found when query has "drums" "drumset" ?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you just have a syntax error.

It's `$elemMatch` and not `eleMatch`

So changing it will work:

```
const match_equipment = await studios.find({equipment: {$elemMatch:{$in: ["mic","amp"]}}});
```

But the essence of `$elemMatch` is more specialised queries. Which in your case are not required. So you can just use the following version utilizing `$in` only:

```
const match_equipment = await studios.find({equipment: {$in: ["mic","amp"]}});
```