# Mongoose $search returning empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm getting an empty array when using `$search` in mongoose.

**Schema**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

studentSchema.index({ name: 'text' });

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
module.exports = Student;
```

**$search**

```js
const Student = require('../models/Student.Model');
(async () => {
    const result = await Student.aggregate([
           {
        $search: {
          index: 'default',
          compound: {
            must: [
              {
                text: {
                  query: 'Lee',
                  path: 'name',
                  fuzzy: {
                     maxEdits: 1,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ]);

})();
```

This gives me an empty array. So I tried another syntax.

```js
const result = await Student.aggregate().search({
      index: 'default',
      compound: {
        must: [
          {
            text: {
              query: 'Lee',
              path: 'name',
              fuzzy: {
                maxEdits: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

That also gave me an empty array.

To test whether the model was working I used `find` and `filter`, and could see similar results I'd expect to see with `$search`.

```js
let result2 = await Student.find({});

result2 = result2.filter((p) => p.name.includes('Lee'));
```

`result2` had two documents

```js
result2:  [
  { _id: 625f70ac90e916620045cab5, name: 'Brian Lee', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 625f70e39660b486c82b2011, name: 'Lee Cohen', __v: 0 }
]
```

Update: `find` and `$text` also give me the above correct results, but I want to implement a fuzzy search and I don't think you can with `find` and $text`:

```js
const resultsShort = await Student.find({ $text: { $search: 'Lee' } });
```

Why isn't `$search` returning these two documents?

Comment: It seems like you haven't set up a search index properly. the `$search` functionality works on preprocessed "tokens" based on the index setup

Comment: Isn't `studentSchema.index({ name: 'text' });` supposed to set up a text index? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: `await Student.find({ $text: { $search: 'Lee' } });` this gives me results, so I think the indexes are fine.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like Atlas Search indexes are different from $text indexes, so I think you might have found the problem. When I went on my Atlas dashboard there were no search indexes. Now I'm trying to find out how to create a search index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a $text index not an Atlas Search index:

`studentSchema.index({ name: 'text' });`

The above can be removed.

You can't create an Atlas Search index on a mongoose schema, it has to be set on the Atlas site or the CLI.

To create an Atlas Search index, go to your database on cloud.mongodb.com ->**Search**-->**Create Search Index**-->**JSON Editor**-->**Next**-->pick your collection--> set the index name. here it would be 'default'

Then set the index:

```json
{ 
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic":false,
    "fields":{
    "name":{
    "analyzer":"lucene.standard",
    "type":"string"
    }
  }
}
```

Then this code works.

````
const result = await Student.aggregate().search({
      index: 'default',
      compound: {
        must: [
          {
            text: {
              query: 'Lee',
              path: 'name',
              fuzzy: {
                maxEdits: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
    ```
````

Answer (score -1):

Use `$regex`

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    $regex: "Lee"
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n8RZho63QIh)

---

createIndex

```
db.collection.createIndex({name:"text"})
```

text search

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "Lee"}})
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to use fuzzy search.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss How about text search. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to do a fuzzy search? Fuzzy search is where even if a word is spelled wrong it will still search for similar words. I thought you could do it with mongo, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss Check [fuzzy-searching-with-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421664/fuzzy-searching-with-mongodb). You can use the Mongo DB Atlas feature where you can search your text based on different [Analyzers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/analyzers/) that MongoDB provides.