# remove a word from txt and save. no similar words

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
<?php

$post="marie" . "\n"; // \n not working?

//replace txt
$oldMessage = $post;
$deletedFormat = "";

//read the entire string
$str=file_get_contents('log.txt');

//replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
$str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);

//write the entire string
file_put_contents('log.txt', $str);

?>
```

I want to find `marie` and replace it:

```
ANAff
marieb
marie
mariec
marie
```

So it should replace only the 3 one, but the result was:

```
ANAff
b

c
```

In other words, I want to remove the exactly $post value from log.txt. how to do this?
And if possible, how to remove the full line? not let it blank.

Comment: Not sure if that question is good itself, but that requirement surely is and is interesting as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
echo preg_replace('/marie\b/', '', $str);
```

Comment: nice! sometimes I have urls too, like: `http://www.stac`... instead of marie I put this URL and it is not working. maybe because the http:`//` ?

Comment: Yes, you have to escape all special chars like \/

Comment: No, because htmlspecialchars is for html rendering. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript