# Not enough )'s when parsing an user's input that contains one parenthesis

Tags: c#

When an user inputs a string that only contains one parenthesis, the `Regex.IsMatch()` breaks. Inputting a single `[` also breaks the program.

```
Regex.IsMatch("John Cena", "Test(", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

In this case `John Cena` is the name from my database. The user then inputs `Test(` in the search input, but the server will return an 500 error, because `Regex.IsMatch()` breaks because of the input.

How do I escape all of these, so I can actually test one input to the one I have in my database? I simply want to test if the user's input matches the entry from the database. And yes, the name from the database can contain a parenthesis, so it would be nice if `John Cena(` would match the user's input, if he types `John Cena(`.

Comment: If you need to search for string such "John Cena", (and deal with user input), maybe a Regex is not the right tool.
`int index = input.IndexOf("John Cena", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` will work in such scenario

Comment: Allowing a user created regular expressions in your back-end can be a vector for a denial of service attack: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: @MartinLiversage So IndexOf would be prefered, even though I now escape the input?

Comment: @Snorlax: If you escape the input then there is no possibility of a denial of service attack but I'm not sure that regex is the right tool then. In your case the regex will be a simple substring search.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yeah that's true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Regex.Escape* turns all regex control characters in a string to their escape codes:

```
Regex.IsMatch("John Cena", Regex.Escape(userinput), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

But why use regex at all? Simple string functions will do the same in this case:

```
"John Cena".IndexOf(userinput, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
```

Comment: Hell yeah, this is what I needed. I didn't know `Regex.Escape()` would just escape them for me. Works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`(` is a reserved char, escape it with `\`

Comment: So I would basically have to escape every single character? Doesn't seem like a good workaround. Escape (, ), [, ], etc.

Comment: You can search for special chars and perform a replace. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript

Comment: You can use Regex.Escape too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your name with a Regex you cannot escape these characters. The only way is to catch the `ArgumentException` and handle it properly:

```
var result;
try
{
    result = Regex.IsMatch("John Cena", "Test(", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
}
catch(ArgumentException)
{
    //invalid regex -> use false or true as a constant value
    result = false;//matches nothing
}
```

Or if you don't want to compare the name with a regex, you can escape it:

```
Regex.IsMatch("John Cena", Regex.Escape("Test("), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

`Regex.Escape` adds a `\` before all characters which must be escaped.
But in this case the Regex is useless and you can use the **faster** string method:

```
"John Cena".IndexOf("Test(", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```