# escaping special characters in vba is not working

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I don't know why but I can't escape special characters in patterns.

```
If StrTest Like "\[*\]" Then ...
```

It still does not match values like [1234567890].
In other threads I read that "\" is used to escape characters, but it does still not work.

In between the brackets I want any string to be possible.

Comment: If any of these answers helped you please consider [accepting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards those who help you.  It also helps others with the same problem to find a working answer.

Answer (score 3):

When using the VBA `Like` operator, you are supposed to escape special characters by enclosing them in square brackets (`[` and `]`). What you are using above is syntax for a regular expression, which is not the same thing as a `Like` pattern. See [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235204(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information about the differences between `Like` and regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution below using `RegEx.Replace` method.

**Note**: special thanks for helping with the `Pattern` from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearData()

Dim StrTest As String
Dim Result  As String
Dim Reg1    As Object

StrTest = "[1234567890]"

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg1
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\/^$|#\s]" ' escape special characters pattern
End With

If Reg1.test(StrTest) Then
    Result = Reg1.Replace(StrTest, Result)
End If

End SUb
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
Sub no_spch()

For Each cell In range("a1:a10")
spch = "#+-,'.()[]!?`&:*"
For i = 1 To Len(spch)
cell.Value = Replace(Replace(cell.Value, Mid(spch, i, 1), ""), " ", "")
Next
Next

End Sub
```