# Why is new RegEx not working properly

Tags: javascript

For some reason…

When ever I try to get the `Object.keys` from `replace.letters` and use the `Object.keys` in a `new RegExp` `joined` by `|`…

The `new RegExp` only recognize some of the `Object.keys` but not all of them. I need the `RegEx` to dynamically create itself.

If I place a static `RegExp` in… It works perfectly fine.

1. Demo does not work properly
2. Demo works perfectly `but I have to force the Regex to know what to look for`

```js
replace = {
  letters: {
    a: {
      after: ["til"]
    },
    b: {
      because: ["bec"]
    },
    c: {
      cool: ["chill"]
    },
    e: {
      energy: ["en"]
    },
    h: {
      light: ["look"]
    },
    i: {
      keen: ["ok"]
    },
    r: {
      roll: ["rock"]
    },
    s: {
      ship: ["skip"]
    },
    t: {
      trip: ["tip"]
    }
  }
}

sentence = [
  "If you want a cookie, eat your dinner.",
  "As soon as you enter the house, change clean your room and mop the floor.",
  "So long as I'm king, I will ensure your safty.",
  "Change the curtains, after house is painted.",
  "Change the curtains, by the time that we are headed.",
  "Assuming that you are a good person, hold my beer.",
  "Reject the offer, even if I'm not there.",
  "Reject the offer, zoom I'm not there.",
  "By the time the bus gets here, the show will be over with.",
  "Choose a random number.",
  "Try not to mess this, that and those up.",
  "Change a random number, pick a color, and put it in jason's house.",
  "Zoom, fix and lower the bar.",
  "Don't change the house.",
  "Create a playground.",
  "While you were gone, I changed the lockes",
  "Before I stop the car, can you get my wallet."
]
let objects_letters = Object.keys(replace.letters).join('|')
let letters_RegEx = new RegExp('^(' + objects_letters + ')', 'gi')
console.log(letters_RegEx)//This isn't working properly.

for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  let $this = sentence[i]
  let commaKey = /,/g.test($this)
  let if_While_Key = /^(If|While)/gi.test($this)


  //Here is the problem
  let letterKey = letters_RegEx.test($this)
  //Here is the problem


  if (commaKey) {
    if (if_While_Key) {}
    if (letterKey) {
      $('body').append($this + '<br>');
    } else {}
  } else {}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
replace = {
  letters: {
    a: {
      after: ["til"]
    },
    b: {
      because: ["bec"]
    },
    c: {
      cool: ["chill"]
    },
    e: {
      energy: ["en"]
    },
    h: {
      light: ["look"]
    },
    i: {
      keen: ["ok"]
    },
    r: {
      roll: ["rock"]
    },
    s: {
      ship: ["skip"]
    },
    t: {
      trip: ["tip"]
    }
  }
}

sentence = [
  "If you want a cookie, eat your dinner.",
  "As soon as you enter the house, change clean your room and mop the floor.",
  "So long as I'm king, I will ensure your safty.",
  "Change the curtains, after house is painted.",
  "Change the curtains, by the time that we are headed.",
  "Assuming that you are a good person, hold my beer.",
  "Reject the offer, even if I'm not there.",
  "Reject the offer, zoom I'm not there.",
  "By the time the bus gets here, the show will be over with.",
  "Choose a random number.",
  "Try not to mess this, that and those up.",
  "Change a random number, pick a color, and put it in jason's house.",
  "Zoom, fix and lower the bar.",
  "Don't change the house.",
  "Create a playground.",
  "While you were gone, I changed the lockes",
  "Before I stop the car, can you get my wallet."
]
let objects_letters = Object.keys(replace.letters).join('|')
let letters_RegEx = new RegExp('^(' + objects_letters + ')', 'gi')
console.log(letters_RegEx)//This isn't working properly.

for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  let $this = sentence[i]
  let commaKey = /,/g.test($this)
  let if_While_Key = /^(If|While)/gi.test($this)


  //Here is the problem
  let letterKey = /^(a|b|c|e|h|i|r|s|t)/gi.test($this)
  //Here is the problem


  if (commaKey) {
    if (if_While_Key) {}
    if (letterKey) {
      $('body').append($this + '<br>');
    } else {}
  } else {}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does it work with grep or something like that on the command line?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `grep()`

Comment: I just want to test for `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your `RegExp Flags`

Change

```
let letters_RegEx = new RegExp('^(' + objects_letters + ')', 'gi')
```

to

```
let letters_RegEx = new RegExp('^(' + objects_letters + ')', 'i')
```

```js
replace = {
  letters: {
    a: {
      after: ["til"]
    },
    b: {
      because: ["bec"]
    },
    c: {
      cool: ["chill"]
    },
    e: {
      energy: ["en"]
    },
    h: {
      light: ["look"]
    },
    i: {
      keen: ["ok"]
    },
    r: {
      roll: ["rock"]
    },
    s: {
      ship: ["skip"]
    },
    t: {
      trip: ["tip"]
    }
  }
}

sentence = [
  "If you want a cookie, eat your dinner.",
  "As soon as you enter the house, change clean your room and mop the floor.",
  "So long as I'm king, I will ensure your safty.",
  "Change the curtains, after house is painted.",
  "Change the curtains, by the time that we are headed.",
  "Assuming that you are a good person, hold my beer.",
  "Reject the offer, even if I'm not there.",
  "Reject the offer, zoom I'm not there.",
  "By the time the bus gets here, the show will be over with.",
  "Choose a random number.",
  "Try not to mess this, that and those up.",
  "Change a random number, pick a color, and put it in jason's house.",
  "Zoom, fix and lower the bar.",
  "Don't change the house.",
  "Create a playground.",
  "While you were gone, I changed the lockes",
  "Before I stop the car, can you get my wallet."
]
let objects_letters = Object.keys(replace.letters).join('|')
let letters_RegEx = new RegExp('^(' + objects_letters + ')', 'i')
console.log(letters_RegEx)//This isn't working properly.

for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  let $this = sentence[i]
  let commaKey = /,/g.test($this)
  let if_While_Key = /^(If|While)/gi.test($this)


  //Here is the problem
  let letterKey = letters_RegEx.test($this)
  //Here is the problem


  if (commaKey) {
    if (if_While_Key) {}
    if (letterKey) {
      $('body').append($this + '<br>');
    } else {}
  } else {}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to precede special characters with \ when included in a string ([RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)).

**EDIT:** it looks like you need to escape all the special characters in regexp. I have borrowed `escapeRegExp` function from [Mathias Bynens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)

Please see corrected snippet below:

```js
replace = {
  letters: {
    a: {
      after: ["til"]
    },
    b: {
      because: ["bec"]
    },
    c: {
      cool: ["chill"]
    },
    e: {
      energy: ["en"]
    },
    h: {
      light: ["look"]
    },
    i: {
      keen: ["ok"]
    },
    r: {
      roll: ["rock"]
    },
    s: {
      ship: ["skip"]
    },
    t: {
      trip: ["tip"]
    }
  }
}

sentence = [
  "If you want a cookie, eat your dinner.",
  "As soon as you enter the house, change clean your room and mop the floor.",
  "So long as I'm king, I will ensure your safty.",
  "Change the curtains, after house is painted.",
  "Change the curtains, by the time that we are headed.",
  "Assuming that you are a good person, hold my beer.",
  "Reject the offer, even if I'm not there.",
  "Reject the offer, zoom I'm not there.",
  "By the time the bus gets here, the show will be over with.",
  "Choose a random number.",
  "Try not to mess this, that and those up.",
  "Change a random number, pick a color, and put it in jason's house.",
  "Zoom, fix and lower the bar.",
  "Don't change the house.",
  "Create a playground.",
  "While you were gone, I changed the lockes",
  "Before I stop the car, can you get my wallet."
]
let objects_letters = Object.keys(replace.letters).join('\|')
let letters_RegEx = new RegExp(escapeRegExp('^(' + objects_letters + ')'), 'i')
console.log(letters_RegEx);

function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\$&');
}

for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  let $this = sentence[i]
  let commaKey = /,/g.test($this)
  
  let if_While_Key = /^(If|While)/gi.test($this)

  //FIXED
  let letterKey = letters_RegEx.exec($this)

  if (commaKey) {
    if (if_While_Key) {}
    if (letterKey) {
      $('body').append($this + '<br>');
    } else {}
  } else {}



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Zoom, fix and lower the bar.` should be written in HTML

Comment: Nor does `Don't change the house.`

Comment: Only 12 Sentences should be written to the HTML