# how to escape double quotes inside a json

Tags: json, regex

I'm trying to create a JSON file which will hold a regular expression.
for example:

```
    {
    "FrameworksData": [{
            "name": "jquery",
            "regexes": ["script\s+src\s*=\s*\"jquery", "b", "c"],
            "extensions": [".js"],
            "conditions":"t1=r1||r2||r3; t2=t1&&e1; res=t2;"            
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to use the double/single quotes as part of the regex that is located inside the JSON. However this JSON is not valid as a result of the structure \"jquery.
how do I use the single quotes and the double quotes in the JSON so I can achieve the correct regex?
Thanks!

Comment: Let's take a step back.  Who/what is generating the above JSON?  Ideally, the escaping should already be handled for you.  Most likely, content double quotes would just be escaped with a single backslash (I think).

Comment: I'm creating this JSON manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple techniques can be adopted:

1. Escape the backslash `\` i.e to `\\`. For scripted escaping you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)

`"FrameworksData": [{"regexes": ["script\\s+src\\s*=\\s*\"jquery", "b", "c"]}]`

2. You can use encodeURIComponent to transfer the regexes if you don't want to escape.