# Match Non-Consecutive Duplicate Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

I want to match duplicate characters that are separated by other characters:

- Matching `stress` should return `sss`
- Matching `lambda` should return `aa`
- Matching `moonmen` should return `moonmn`

I am close, getting the first character of every duplicate by using lookaheads:

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/NMOMhZ/1)

```js
['stress','lambda','moonmen'].forEach( (e) => {
  console.log( e.match(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g) )
} )
```

But how would I get all duplicate characters?

Comment: Regex is not usually for this kind of task, it is inefficient and requires code tweaks anyway as you cannot achieve this "in one regex go".

Comment: The regex could be simplified if you sort the characters first.

Comment: [(\[a-zA-Z\])(?=(?:(?!\1).)+\1)](https://regex101.com/r/hz3m0j/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern matches the latest character that has a duplicate.

As an alternative, knowing that they have a duplicate, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to remove all the non duplicates.

```js
let pattern = /(.)(?=.*\1)/g;
[
  "stress",
  "lambda",
  "moonmen"
].forEach(s => {
  let regex = new RegExp("[^" + [...new Set(s.match(pattern))].join('') + "]+", "g");
  console.log(s.replace(regex, ''));
});
```

If you want to account for special characters in the string, you might use the function on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310752/5424988) to escape characters with special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty complex, my guess is that maybe this expression might be an step closer:

```
(?:(.)(?=(.*)\1))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tJOFMS/1)