# replace duplicate characters from strings

Tags: r, tidyr, gsub, stringr

I am trying to remove duplicate character from strings.

```
dput(test)
c("APAAAAAAAAAAAPAAPPAPAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPAPAAAAAAPPAPAAAPAPAAAAP", 
"AAA", "P", "P", "A", "P", "P", "APPPPPA", "A", "P", "AA", "PP", 
"PPA", "P", "P", "A", "P", "APAP", "P", "PA")
```

I create one function to sort the string

```
strSort <- function(x)
  sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")
```

Then i use gsub to remove consecutive characters

```
gsub("(.)\\1{2,}", "\\1", str_Sort(test))
```

This give out put as

```
gsub("(.)\\1{2,}", "\\1", strSort(test))
 [1] "AP"   "A"    "P"    "P"    "A"    "P"    "P"    "AAP"  "A"    "P"    "AA"   "PP"   "APP"  "P"    "P"    "A"    "P"    "AAPP" "P"    "AP"
```

Output should only have one A and/or one P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex you can do :

```
gsub('(?:(.)(?=(.*)\\1))', '', test, perl = TRUE)

#[1] "AP" "A"  "P"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "P"  "PA" "A"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "PA"
#[14] "P"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "AP" "P"  "PA"
```

The regex has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171644/3962914).

Answer (score 1):

In the `strsplit` output, we need to use `unique` on the `sort`ed elements

```
sapply(strsplit(test, ""), function(x) 
       paste(unique(sort(x)), collapse=""))
#[1] "AP" "A"  "P"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "P"  "AP" "A"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "AP" "P"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "AP" "P"  "AP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `utf8ToInt` + `intToUtf8`

```
> sapply(test, function(x) intToUtf8(sort(unique(utf8ToInt(x)))), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
 [1] "AP" "A"  "P"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "P"  "AP" "A"  "P"  "A"  "P"  "AP" "P"  "P" 
[16] "A"  "P"  "AP" "P"  "AP"
```