# Replace certain strings globaly

Tags: javascript

Sorry, this sounds very basic, but I really can't find on Google.

In order to replace contents in a string globally, you can use things like...

```
 a.replace(/blue/g,'red')
```

But sometimes you need to replace characters that's not compatible with the example above, for example, the character ")"

So, this will fail...

```
const a ="Test(123)"
a = a.replace(/(/g, '')

VM326:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group
```

How to replace string of characters like that ?
    at :1:7

Comment: escape it? `/\(/g`

Comment: `a.replace(/\(/g, '')` escape

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape regular expression special characters using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: it should also be `let a = "Test(123)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special regular expression characters are:

```
. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -
```

```js
const a ="Test(123)";
console.log(a.replace(/\(/g, ''));
```

you need to use the escape char `\` for this. there are set of char which need to be escaped in this replace(regex)

```
a.replace(/\(/g, '');
```

Find a full details here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the ( with \ in a new variable because a is const 
and it will work

```
var b = a.replace(/\(/g, '');
```

for more practicing use this site 
[regExr](https://regexr.com/)