# Highlight matching keywords within a text string with bold font

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating function in which I will pass String and Specific text.The specific text should be bold in whole string. I want to achieve this but unable do that.

Input string:-"Hi Hello boy Hello Shyam Hello"

Text :- Hello.

Output:- Hello word should looks bold in String.

Comment: You tagged Reactjs, it is related? Do you have a concrete example? Are you referring to vanilla javascript? What have you tried? Share some code.

Comment: you can try this - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_bold.asp

Comment: I approved the suggested edit for removing the ReactJS tag because it didn't look related; feel free to restore it if you feel necessary.

Comment: to all the `RegExp` based approaches ... is anyone aware of that the provided search string might contain whitespace sequences(of different length) and characters that are regexp-control characters itself (thus they need to be escaped before feeding them to the `RegExp` function/constructor). Also the text this search string is supposed to match might contain whitespace sequence(s) of unknown length (thus text content needs to be sanitized before as well).

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```js
function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\\s]/g, '\\$&');
}

function boldMe(input, text){
    const regExString = escapeRegExp(text)
    const regex = new RegExp(regExString, 'g');
    let output = input.replace(regex, `<b>${text}</b>`);
    console.log(output);
    return output;
}

var myDev = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDev.innerHTML = boldMe(myDev.innerHTML,'Hello');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Hi Hello boy Hello Shyam Hello</div>
```

---

Edit:

As [@Peter Seliger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627243/peter-seliger) pointed out in the comments, since working with regex, the search string has to be escaped before being used. I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310752/3125277), but feel free to use any other escaping implementation

Comment: Hi <b>Hello</b> boy <b>Hello</b>......I am getting this.<b> not rendering..why??

Comment: where and how do you render it? can you show the code?

Comment: Hi <b>Hello</b> boy <b>Hello</b>......I am getting this instead of bold the text.

Comment: yes, but how are you writing it back in the DOM? you need to use the `.innerHTML` property... that's why I ask you how do you render it, so the code you use to display the string

Comment: ... regarding to what I was commenting on the OP's post ... a simple string like ... *Hi Hello boy hello Shyam Hello (Hello)* ... where one just wants to highlight the `(Hello)` (alltogether with its parenthesis) does result in something like this ... *Hi (**Hello**) boy hello Shyam (**Hello**) ((**Hello**))*.

Comment: @PeterSeliger good catch, I updated the answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

```js
function boldString (fString, bString) {
 
  let regex = new RegExp(bString, 'g');

  return fString.replace(regex, `<b>${bString}</b>`);  
}

let output = boldString("Hi Hello boy Hello Shyam Hello", "Hello");

console.log(output);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would really make your answer useful

Comment: Hi <b>Hello</b> boy <b>Hello</b>......I am getting this instead of bold the text.

Comment: @Sharad_kumar I have edited code to see the output. Earlier you were seeing output in console.

Answer (score -1):

```
<span id="boldit">Bold me</span>

<script>
  function boldme() {
    document.getElementById('boldit').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }
  boldme();
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you @leopal