# Javascript regex replace global object property with brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, where I want to replace global myObj.value with myObj.name. I tried to construct a new RegExp object, but how to pass the square brackets ?

```
let param = {
  name: '[year]',
  value: '2019'
}

let str = 'Enter the number of days during [year] (they should not be more than your total days spent 
           during [year])'
```

I tried:

```
 str.replace(new RegExp('param.name', 'g'), param.value);
```

and

```
str.replace(new RegExp(`\\[param.name\\]`, 'g'), param.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape regex special characters in your 'name' parameter by using a custom function to do that. Below is a sample with a custom function to replace special regex characters obtained from [How to escape regular expression special characters using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript).

```js
let param = {
  name: '[year]',
  value: '2019'
}

let str = 'Enter the number of days during [year] (they should not be more than your total days spent during [year])'

function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
}

alert(str);

str = str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(param.name), 'g'), param.value);

alert(str);
```