# Failing to replace characters of a string inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, replace

my code is like that..

```
function replaceAll(str, from, to) {
  let result = ''
  for(let i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++) 
  if(str[i]===from) {
       result = str.replace(from,to) 
     }
   }
   return result; 
 }
```

i wanna return like that

```
let output = replaceAll('loop', 'o', 'e');
console.log(output); // --> 'leep'
```

but it's only changed 'leop'

Comment: it is quite unclear, why you need a loop here.

Comment: @NinaScholz to deal with the fact that `replace(string, ...)` only replaces the first occurance of that string. But the entire construct is cumbersome and only works as long as `from.length === 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem in two ways:

- using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function (supported by every browser) with the global modifier (`/…/g`) to replace all the occurrences
- using [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) function (supported by Chrome 85+, Edge 85+, Firefox 77+, Opera 71+, Safari 13.1+; not supported by Internet Explorer)

```js
let str = 'loop';
console.log(str.replace(/o/g, 'e'));
console.log(str.replaceAll('o', 'e'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceAll()` function in JavaScript.

```js
const str = 'loop';
console.log(str.replaceAll('o', 'e'));
```

Comment: In fact, I used loop to study, but It's really simple!. okay i will consider :)

Answer (score 1):

**Why?**

for simple replace only replace the first matching text. So you need to use `g`-*Global text match* mode. But you are passing from text as variable. so use `RegExp` to create regular expression like

[**`RegExp(from,'g')`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
function replaceAll(str, from, to) {
  return str.replace(RegExp(from,'g'),to)
}

let output = replaceAll('loop', 'o', 'e');
console.log(output); // --> 'leep'
```

Comment: With a construct like this you should always [escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310752/6567275) before passing the string to `RegExp`.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you why it doesn't work.

```
function replaceAll(str, from, to) {
            let result = str;
            for(let i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++) {
                if(str[i]===from) {
                    result = result.replace(from,to);
                }
            }
            return result; 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to take a loop, you need to assign the replaced string to `str` instead to result, because you take the original `str` for replacing, but assigning to `result`.

[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) replaces only the first find of the string. If you take a regular expression you could replace all occcurences directly.

```js
function replaceAll(str, from, to) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === from) {
      str = str.replace(from, to);
    }
  }
  return str;
}


let output = replaceAll('loop', 'o', 'e');
console.log(output); // --> 'leep'
```

Comment: woow.. interesting then doesnt str change?

Comment: `str` is a local variable, and because of handing over a primitive, like a string, you need to assign a new value of the string.

Answer (score 1):

***Let's dive deeper into your problem so that you can understand what is really going on here***

---

```
function replaceAll(str, from, to) {
      let result = ''
          for(let i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++) 
              if(str[i]===from) {
                  result = str.replace(from,to) 
              }
          }
      return result; 
}
```

`str` is a string type variable. String data-type is **value type**. When you change a character in a string it does not rewrite the content of the initial variable. It rather create a new string value and  store it to memory.The previous value is garbage collected.

Initially `str == loop`, now if you change first `'o'` with `'e'` then `str` remains 'loop'. A new data is assigned to `result` variable which holds the value `'leop'`.  That is why in your for loop always same value is being assigned to result variable.

***Let's visualize the process:***

---

```
1st iteration : 
  result = 'loop'.replace('o','e') // leop
  // result is now 'leop' and str remains 'loop'

2nd iteration :
  result = 'loop'.replace('o','e') // leop
 // as str remained 'loop', so result will again be 'leop
```

That's why `result` variable remains the same after the for loop is completed.

---

Another thing to notice, although in 1st and 2nd iterations, value of `result` variable is same (`'leop'`), But in 2nd loop, initial `'leop'` from first loop is `gurbage collected (thrown away)` in order to assign it another value (in our case another `'leop'`)