# PowerShell Replace value in JSON

Tags: powershell

In our Azure CICD Pipeline, we have an element where we are trying to deploy Policies. We have JSON file per policy in the repo and we bring all these json files together into one file as part of CI which later is deployed via the CD. The PowerShell wasn't written by me, but a Microsoft consultant who was on site a few years back.

The problem is that when all the JSON comes together, we get an illegal syntax e.g.
[image]

Altering the code to this works and deploys, but means we have to go through all our files manually replace [ with [[:
[image]

In summary the PowerShell bring all of this together, does some manipulation and outputs to a file in the artifacts folder.

This is just a small snippet of the json, but highlights the area and there are many areas like this in the total json that need replacing:

```
{
"functions": [

],
"variables": {
    "location": "UK South"
},
"resources": [{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Allowed Locations for Resources",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "description": "description.",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "General"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "listOfAllowedLocations": {
                "type": "Array",
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources.",
                    "strongType": "location",
                    "displayName": "Allowed locations"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "uksouth",
                    "ukwest"
                ],
                "defaultValue": [
                    "uksouth",
                    "ukwest"
                ]
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [{
                        "field": "location",
                        "notIn": "[parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "location",
                        "notEquals": "global"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "notEquals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "notEquals": "Microsoft.Resources/b2cDirectories"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "audit"
            }
        }
    },
    "name": "Policy1",
    "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
    "location": "[variables('location')]"
}]
```

}

My PowerShell is intro level at best, so I am struggling to get a replace working.

I can obtain the offending area and replace it in a `Write-Host`, but I don't know how to write the back to the originating object with without making a right mess of things:

```
        if ($content.properties.policyRule.if.allOf -ne $null){
        foreach ($param in $content.properties.policyRule.if.allOf){
            Write-Host "were here..................."
            #$param = ($param | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) })

            if ($param.notIn -ne $null){
                $param.notIn.replace('[', '[[')
                Write-Host $param.notIn
            }    
        }
```

Any suggestions would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the `allOf` node contains an array. Due to the [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) feature you will be able to conveniently **read** the `notIn` property but to **write** to it, you will need to be specific on the index (`[0]`) in the `allOf` node:

```
$Data = ConvertFrom-Json $Json # $Json contains your $Json snippet
$Data.resources.properties.policyRule.if.allOf[0].notIn = "[[parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]"
$Data |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

In case you want to recursively find your items based on e.g. a specific name and value format from a specific property level, you might use this common reusable function to recursively **find** (and **replace**) a node in a complex PowerShell object:

```
function Get-Node {
  [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([Object[]])] param(
    [ScriptBlock]$Where,
    [AllowNull()][Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True, Mandatory = $True)]$InputObject,
    [Int]$Depth = 10
  )
  process {
    if ($_ -isnot [String] -and $Depth -gt 0) {
      if ($_ -is [Collections.IDictionary]) {
        if (& $Where) { $_ }
        $_.get_Values() | Get-Node -Where $Where -Depth ($Depth - 1)
      }
      elseif ($_ -is [Collections.IEnumerable]) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $_.get_Count(); $i++) { $_[$i] | Get-Node -Where $Where -Depth ($Depth - 1) }
      }
      elseif ($Nodes = $_.PSObject.Properties.Where{ $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' }) {
        $Nodes.ForEach{
          if (& $Where) { $_ }
          $_.Value | Get-Node -Where $Where -Depth ($Depth - 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage

**Finding** node(s) with a specific name and value (-format):

```
$Node = $Data.resources.properties.policyRule.if |Get-Node -Where {
    $_.name -eq 'notIn' -and $_.value -Match "^\[\w+\('\w+'\)\]$"
}
$Node
```

```
Value           : [parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]
MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : notIn
IsInstance      : True
```

**Replacing** the value of the found node(s):

```
$Node |ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value  = '[' + $_.Value
}
$Data |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

**Results**

```js
{
  "functions": [],
  "variables": {
"location": "UK South"
  },
  "resources": [
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Allowed Locations for Resources",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "description.",
    "metadata": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "category": "General"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "listOfAllowedLocations": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources.",
          "strongType": "location",
          "displayName": "Allowed locations"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "uksouth",
          "ukwest"
        ],
        "defaultValue": [
          "uksouth",
          "ukwest"
        ]
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "location",
            "notIn": "[[parameters('listOfAllowedLocations')]"
          },
          {
            "field": "location",
            "notEquals": "global"
          },
          {
            "field": "type",
            "notEquals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "type",
            "notEquals": "Microsoft.Resources/b2cDirectories"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
  },
  "name": "Policy1",
  "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "location": "[variables('location')]"
}
  ]
}
```

---

**Update 2022-11-21**

- Resolved an issue with `$Null` values in the `Get-Node` function, see also: [PowerShell FilterScript error with some JSON Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74510548/1701026) (thanks 
  **[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74510548/45375)**).

Comment: Many thanks iRon, this is very close to what I need. What if I wanted to search for other values and not just [parameters e.g. [concat, [uniqueString. The list totals about 20. Will I need to list all? I've tried "\[\('\w+'\)\]", but that doesn't pick up any

Comment: You will need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3115150/1701026) any (square) brackets as they have a special meaning for a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Something like: `^\[w+\('\w+'\)\]$`

Comment: Really good answer and very detailed. Many thanks iRon