# Powershell Json Array

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

In relation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510152/powershell-filterscript-error-with-some-json-files) that was answered, we now have an issue where some values are arrays and we need to retain that structure

The code as it stands is:

```
function Get-Node {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([Object[]])] param(
      [ScriptBlock]$Where,
      [AllowNull()]   
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True, Mandatory = $True)]$InputObject,
      [Int]$Depth = 90
    )
    process {
      if ($_ -isnot [String] -and $Depth -gt 0) {
        if ($_ -is [Collections.IDictionary]) {
          if (& $Where) { $_ }
          $_.get_Values() | Get-Node -Where $Where -Depth ($Depth - 1)
        }
        elseif ($_ -is [Collections.IEnumerable]) {
          for ($i = 0; $i -lt $_.get_Count(); $i++) { 
            $_[$i] | Get-Node -Where $Where -Depth ($Depth - 1) 
        }
        }
        elseif ($Nodes = $_.PSObject.Properties.Where{ $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' }) {
          $Nodes.ForEach{
            if (& $Where) { $_ }
            $_.Value | Get-Node -Where $Where -Depth ($Depth - 1)
            Write-Host "In Second If " $_.Value
            Write-Host "In Second If 2" $_
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the above function is called via:

```
if ($content.properties.policyRule -ne $null){            
            foreach ($rule in $policyRule){
                $Node = $content.properties | Get-Node -Where {$_.name -eq $rule -and $_.value -Match "^\[\w+"} 
                $Node | ForEach-Object {
                    $_.Value  = '[' + $_.Value
                }  
            }
        }
```

And what we are seeing is this:

```
"notIn":  "[[concat(subscription().id,'/')] [subscription().id] /"
```

What we ideally want:

```
"notIn":  ["[[concat(subscription().id,'/')]", "[[subscription().id]", "/"]
```

Any suggestions would be grateful

Comment: Try changing `$_.Value  = '[' + $_.Value` to `$_.Value  = @($_.Value |% {"[${_}"})`

Comment: You're like everyone else who has assisted on this issue Mathias - a lifesaver! Please post as an answer and I'll accept