# Where-Object (or similar) to filter by nested data?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, nested, where-object

```
$DeviceId = "123456789-1234-1234-1234-123123123123"
Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -top 1 -filter "appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In'" | where-object {$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceID -eq $DeviceID} | select-object userdisplayname
```

As part of a larger script, I am pulling a list of AzureAD device IDs into a foreach loop. I would like to then run the above command to only show me the details of each device that matches that device ID. The problem is that the device id is buried under Device Detail. I would like to add a where-object or something similar to compare $DeviceID to $DeviceDetail.DeviceID but that doesn't work. I know I am missing something simple, but I don't really work with data like this.

```
Id                               : 1111111-2223-3333-4444-1234567899
CreatedDateTime                  : 2023-12-06T14:37:09Z
UserDisplayName                  : JANE DOE
UserPrincipalName                : jdoe@contoso.com
UserId                           : 2222222-33333-33333-33333-3333333333
AppId                            : 2222222-33333-33333-33333-3333333333
AppDisplayName                   : Windows Sign In
IpAddress                        : xx.xx.xx.xxx
ClientAppUsed                    : Mobile Apps and Desktop clients
CorrelationId                    : 2222222-33333-33333-33333-3333333333
ConditionalAccessStatus          : notApplied
OriginalRequestId                : 
IsInteractive                    : True
TokenIssuerName                  : 
TokenIssuerType                  : AzureAD
ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds     : 146
RiskDetail                       : hidden
RiskLevelAggregated              : hidden
RiskLevelDuringSignIn            : hidden
RiskState                        : none
RiskEventTypes                   : 
ResourceDisplayName              : Windows Azure Active Directory
ResourceId                       : 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
AuthenticationMethodsUsed        : {}
Status                           : class SignInStatus {
                                     ErrorCode: 0
                                     FailureReason: Other.
                                     AdditionalDetails: 
                                   }
                                   
DeviceDetail                     : class SignInAuditLogObjectDeviceDetail {
                                     DeviceId: 123456789-1234-1234-1234-123123123123
                                     DisplayName: DESKTOP-1234567
                                     OperatingSystem: Windows
                                     Browser: 
                                     IsCompliant: True
                                     IsManaged: True
                                     TrustType: Azure AD joined
                                   }
                                   
Location                         : class SignInAuditLogObjectLocation {
                                     City: Springfield
                                     State: Texas
                                     CountryOrRegion: US
                                   }
                                   
MfaDetail                        : 
AppliedConditionalAccessPolicies : {}
AuthenticationProcessingDetails  : {class AdditionalDetail {
                                     Key: Root Key Type
                                     Value: Unknown
                                   }
                                   }
NetworkLocationDetails           : {class SignInAuditLogObjectNetworkLocationDetails {
                                     NetworkType: trustedNamedLocation
                                     NetworkNames: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
                                   }
                                   }
```

On non-nested data I can just reference the data properties using a where-object, but the data I am trying to retrieve is part of an array and thus I can't get Where-object to filter it.

```
$DeviceId = "123456789-1234-1234-1234-123123123123"
Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -top 1 -filter "appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In'" | where-object {$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceID -eq $DeviceID} | select-object userdisplayname
```

Comment: Maybe this little [`Get-Node`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74474837/1701026) function helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think it looks like you are working with PowerShell and attempting to filter the output of `Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs` based on a nested property (`DeviceDetail.DeviceID`). PowerShell's `Where-Object` cmdlet is indeed the right tool for this task, but you need to ensure that you are referencing the nested property correctly.

In your case, the correct reference to the `DeviceID` property within the `DeviceDetail` property would be `$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceId` (note the lowercase "d" in "DeviceId"). PowerShell is case-sensitive, so it's crucial to use the correct casing for property names.

Here's the corrected code:

```
$DeviceId = "123456789-1234-1234-1234-123123123123"
Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -Top 1 -Filter "appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In'" | Where-Object { $_.DeviceDetail.DeviceId -eq $DeviceId } | Select-Object UserDisplayName
```

Make sure that you use `$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceId` instead of `$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceID`. If the casing is incorrect, the comparison won't work.

This should filter the results based on the specified `$DeviceId`. If you're still facing issues, you might want to examine the output of `Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -Top 1 -Filter "appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In'"` to understand the structure of the data you're working with and ensure that the property names are correct.

Comment: I added the full output of the Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs command in the original post. When I run the command with the correct case as suggested it doesn't return any results...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your whole example is stored under `$resource`
You can just pull the list of device ID via `$resource.DeviceDetail.DeviceId`

I believe it's just formatting issue
Your code is almost correct, just use `-match` instead

```
Get-AzureAdAuditSigninLogs -top 1 -filter "appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In'" | where-object {$_.DeviceDetail.DeviceID -match "$DeviceID" } | select-object userdisplayname
```

More information available in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#examples), see example 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Where-Object` filter is correct, there is no issue there, the issue is your use of `-Top 1` limiting the output to 1 record only thus not finding any results when passed thru your filter. Change `-Top 1` to `-All $true` and the issue should be solved:

```bash
Get-AzureADAuditSigninLogs -All $true -Filter "appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In'" |
    Where-Object { $_.DeviceDetail.deviceId -eq $DeviceID } |
    Select-Object userdisplayname
```

A notable mention, this query is extremely inefficient and unfortunately [the signIn API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signin?view=graph-rest-beta) doesn't support a server side filtering on `deviceDetail/deviceId`:

[image: api is shit]

Otherwise a filter like the below would be possible and would be much more efficient:

```
appdisplayname eq 'Windows Sign In' and deviceDetail/deviceId eq '$DeviceID'
```

However, if you're streaming logs to Log Analytics Workspace or Azure Data Explorer a much more efficient way to get this information would be via KQL Query to `SignInLogs`:

```
SignInLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| where AppDisplayName =~ 'Windows Sign In'
    and DeviceDetail.deviceId == 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
| project UserPrincipalName
```