# how to not render html tags in v-html in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I want to make only matched string bold. Say, I have a string "Hello, World!" and user searched for "hello". I want to make something like this, "**Hello**, World!".

I have tried this,

```js
const search = ref('hello')
function boldText(text) {
    return text.replace(search.value, `<b>${search.value}</b>`)
}
```

```js
<p v-html="boldText('Hello, World!')"></p>
```

But the problem is it is case-sensitive. And it will render if my string contains html tag. If my string is `<div>Hello, World</div>`. It won't show the div tags because I am using `v-html`.

Is there any to solve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following snippet::

```js
const { ref, nextTick } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const search = ref('hello')
    function boldText(text) {
        return text.replace(new RegExp('(' + search.value + ')',"ig"), '<b>$1</b>');
    }
    return { search, boldText }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p v-html="boldText('Hello, World!')"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, case-sensitivity was not a big deal. But, thanks. I have a another problem. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Hey, can you explain the regex? It seems we need to use brackets around `search.value` and what does `$1` mean? Does `$1` means first parameter like bash shell?

Answer (score 0):

Always try to avoid using `v-html` if you can and use render functions instead.

This is the sort of thing that I would create a separate component to do. Using a slot allows you to customize how you want the matched text to be marked up and styled instead of hardcoding a `<b>` tag.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310752/734040
function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const text = Vue.ref('Hello world!')
    const query = Vue.ref('hello')
    
    return { text, query }
  }
})

app.component('SearchHighlight', {
  props: ['text', 'query'],
  
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => {
      if (!props.query) {
        // Small optimization so we don't split a long string into
        // an array of individual characters
        return props.text
      }
      
      const re = RegExp(`(${escapeRegExp(props.query)})`, 'i')
      const parts = props.text.split(re)

      return parts.map((part, i) => {
        // Every odd element is the matched text
        return i % 2 === 0
          ? part
          : slots.default(part)
      })
    }
  },
})


app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="search" v-model="query">
  <div>
    <search-highlight :text="text" :query="query" v-slot="highlight">
      <strong>{{ highlight }}</strong>
    </search-highlight>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution. This might not be best practice or secure. Anyway, I modified the boldText function something like,

```
function boldText(text) {
  let newText = text.replace('<', '&lt;')
  newText = newText.replace('>', '&gt;')
  newText = newText.replace('/', '&#x2215;')
  // these three lines prevents browser from rendering html tags
  return newText.replace(new RegExp('(' + search.value + ')', 'gi'), '<b>$1</b>') // this ensures case-sensitivity and replace text in whole text instead of first match
}
```