# Delete folder files starting with a word in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodejs.

Hi, I need to delete all files starting with a word in a folder.

I have tried the next code but no look:

```
const deleteFile = (path, regex) => {
  fs.readdirSync(path)
    .filter(f => regex.test(f))
    .map(f => fs.unlinkSync(path + f));
};

const starting_filename="name_to_delete";

if (tenantInstance.companyLogoUrl) {
    const path = join(__dirname, "..", "..", "..", "public");
    const regex = `/^${starting_filename}+/`;
    deleteFile(path, new RegExp(regex));
  }
```

Comment: But, How the regex will know that I want only files starting with a word if I dont do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slashes are part of the syntax of RegExp literals, you don't wrap them around the string when using `new RegExp()` -- that will try to match literal slash characters.

You don't need `+` at the end of the RegExp. That matches 1 or more of the last character of `starting_filename`. This is redundant when you're using `test()` rather than `match()`, since it doesn't matter how far the match reaches.

```
const regex = `^${starting_filename}`;
```

Note that this will not work if `starting_filename` contains any characters that have special meaning in a regular expression, they need to be escaped. See [How to escape regular expression special characters using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, But is deleting only one file starting with the name. Other files stay in the folder.

Comment: This is what I did: const deleteFile = (path, regex) => {
  fs.readdirSync(path)
    .filter(f => regex.test(f))
    .map(f => {
      console.log(`${path}/${f}`);
      return fs.unlinkSync(`${path}/${f}`);
    });
};
and  const regex = `^${starting_filename}`;

Comment: Does it show all the filenames in `console.log()`?

Comment: There's no need to return anything, since you're not doing anything with the returned values. And you should use `forEach()` instead of `map()` since you don't use the returned array.